# How to get multiple output between two words if a third word is present using Regex?

Tags: regex

String = `I <am a insta good </boy>.Why,I <am a insta bad </boy>.Where,I <am a naughty </boy>.How,I <am a soft </toy>.Don't know,I <am a very good </boy>.Why so, I <am a very bad </boy>.That's why`

I want output where insta is between these two words like this

```
<am a insta good </boy>
<am a insta bad </boy>
```

I tried `/(<am)(.*)(<\/boy>)/g` this but I am getting many output. Not what I want means those 5 lines.

Comment: `/(<am)(.*?)(<\/boy>)/g`

Comment: Yes, right that - https://regex101.com/r/Byb5ky/2.

Comment: above regex is matching ```<am a soft </toy>.Don\'t know,I <am a very good </boy>```
better not to capture toy ```/(<am)([^<]+)(<\/boy>)/g```
Additionnally capturing does not seem to be what the user wants so we can skip the parenthesis: ```/<am[^<]+<\/boy>/g```

Comment: @user753642 thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have changed question. Can you remove duplication tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to get a substring between 2 strings *not* having a third substring in between, your only 1-pass regex solution is using a [*tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970). See [these best practice guidelines](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

> **When to Use this Technique**
>   Suppose our boss now tells us that we still want to match up to and including `{END}`, but that we also need to avoid stepping over a `{MID}` section, if it exists. Starting with the lazy dot-star version to ensure we match up to the `{END}` delimiter, we can then temper the dot to ensure it doesn't roll over `{MID}`:
>                                                `{START}(?:(?!{MID}).)*?{END}`

```
/(<am)((?:(?!<am|<\/boy>|insta).)*insta.*?)(<\/boy>)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xNDVUP/1)

Note I kept the capturing groups intact, feel free to keep only those you need.

**Pattern details**:

- `(<am)` - `<am` substring
- `(?:(?!<am|<\/boy>|insta).)*` - the tempered greedy token matching any char but a line break char `.` that does not start any of the sequences defined in the negative lookahead: `<am`, `</boy>` or `insta`
- `insta` - an `insta` substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `(<\/boy>)` - `</boy>` substring.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.